# trying to restrict user input for zero position of string

Tags: angular

I want to restrict the user to give a negative sign to the number at the beginning only because when wrong data is given it is being stored in database and the front end is being disturbed by that.
i have tried

```
if(e .key Code == 109)
{
return ;
}
```

Comment: u should never trust the client, always have back-end validation along with front-end validation

Comment: yes. even i felt that the backed validation could solve the issue. Thank you

Comment: You could take the user input and remove the minus sign yourself, and also in the backend you should always verify whether the input is what you are expecting and raise exceptions or generate error messages otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a numeric input as follow:

```
<input type="number" min="0"></input>
```

Which will prevent a number from going below 0.

If you absolutely need a text input, the best way to do it is to simply validate using a Regular Expression or string functions and provide an error message with appropriate CSS to tell the user that he isn't authorized to use a negative sign. Giving feedback to the user is a lot better than preventing them from doing something entirely as it might confuse them.

As mentioned in a comment, you should always validate on your back-end / server side. That is where you protect your database from wrong data. Always assume the user will try to break your work and find the best ways to give them as much freedom as you can while keeping control over all of their actions.

Edit: I misread your question. If you want to prevent the user to write a negative sign at a position other than in front, either use a number input (without the min) or do a simple validation. You can use the FormsModule of Angular as well which has a few validators included, including regex validation,  or which allows for custom validators.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `onlyNumber` custom directive and add a condition to allow negative (e.keyCode 109, 189) at index 0 of the number.

only-number.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumber {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() onlyNumber: boolean;
  @Input() inputValue: number;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.onlyNumber) {
      // console.log(this.inputValue);
      // console.log(e);
      if((this.inputValue == undefined ||this.inputValue.length == 0) 
          && (e.keyCode == 189 || e.keyCode == 109)){
          return;
      }
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Value" 
         [(ngModel)]="inputVal"
         [inputValue]="inputVal"
         onlyNumber="true" >
</md-input-container>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ygncbydEqWKbdx4tFg0l?p=preview)

Comment: i am a little confused her. I want the user to enter -99 but not 99- or some non numbers. Thank you

Comment: Ahhh, I read your requirement literally, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ RamakanthReddy Kowdampalli, please check the updated answer

Comment: thank you for the help, but still i am having the same problem even i tried to create a directive

Comment: Please add the code in original question, or create a plunker and share the link. It's hard to read code from comments.

Comment: I am sorry, i am unable to enter the code here. please check this link  https://embed.plnkr.co/sWH6PXspwabn3d60uMws/

Comment: @RamakanthReddy Kowdampalli, I have updated the answer that uses custom directive to allow negative only at first position.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Nehal. The code works but i am unable to use it in my code. if you don't mind,can we chat .

Comment: yes,but i am getting an error there         ERROR in C:/Users/Ramakanth/Desktop/pb/rk/src/app/OnlyNumbers.directive.ts (120,58): Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: so, i changed inputValue to string, it doesn't give me expected result.

Comment: `inputValue` is not a `string`, it's a number. Are you providing both parameters to the directive,  `[inputValue]`="your input variable name" and `onlyNumber="true"` ??

Comment: Hii. i have done both ways. .<input [inputValue]="heatoil_value" OnlyNumber="true"

Comment: If you copied my directive, then it should be **onlyNumber="true"**, I am not using capital "O"

Comment: inputValue is number  but we are using  this.inputValue.length, so it is giving an error that length can not be used for numbers

Comment: I used it only after checking if `inputValue` is `undefined`. You can take that flag out if it's stopping your from getting it to work.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1PXDk8vVaut2cn9AbQ3S?p=catalogue           . this is where i am trying to implement the functionality

Comment: length is important here because it is  only restricting user to give (-) sign in first place only

Comment: what value `heatoil_value` is initialized with?? and what is the `type` of `heatoil_value`?

Comment: You are using `[ngModel]="sellingpoint.diesel_value` for binding but passing `heatoil_value` to directive, which doesn't make sense. At this point, I can only help if you can create a plunker that reproduces your issue :)

Comment: May be i can share my screen with you, because i do not know how to create a plunker, as it is a big project and there are lot of dependencies.

Comment: You are using [ngModel]="sellingpoint.diesel_value for binding but passing heatoil_value to directive, I did it on purpose, was just testing